# Adding bibliographic information on arXiv

Tags: citations, arxiv

ArXiv offers the option to add bibliographic information once a paper is published in a journal. To do so, it asks me to add a Journal Reference and the Journal version DOI. Does ArXiv gather the remaining required information just from this reference, or does it take this information from the preprint?

If it is the latter, what happens if, for example the title differs slightly or the order of the authors changed in the journal? Which version is taken?

My supervisor mentioned that he once merged two preprints into one journal paper with different title and somehow managed to add the bibliographic information without having to update both papers (which would be bad practise as then two identical papers would be uploaded - providing arXiv allows), but he couldn't figure out any more how exactly that worked.

Furthermore, how does arXiv determine the Bibtex identifyer? Can I fix something like Surname_YEAR manually, to avoid some weird abbreviations, or is this done automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my own most recent paper that was published under a slightly different title to the preprint (the journal just added a couple of hyphens), it appears that the bibTeX citation available on arXiv correctly reports the published title. It also includes information that is not contained in the journal reference, such as the publisher field. Below the bibTeX citation field, it says "Data provided by: Crossref Citation Formating Service", which I interpret as meaning that arXiv uses e.g. the DOI of the published article to ask Crossref for the full citation, rather than generating it themselves. This can be contrasted with preprints without journal reference, where it instead says "Data provided by: arXiv API" below the bibTeX field.

> Furthermore, how does arXiv determine the Bibtex identifyer? Can I fix something like Surname_YEAR manually, to avoid some weird abbreviations, or is this done automatically?

arXiv sometimes adds some word from the title to the identifier to help distinguish different papers by the same author, but I don't think you have control over this on arxiv.org. Of course, you can rename them to your heart's content in your own .bib files.

Comment: Thanks, that already answered all my questions!